# SImple pregmatch with negation and group

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string where valid entry is 's' 'a' 't' or 'b' OR the string 'all'. I seek to know when the entry is invalid. Negation seems called for to test for a bad string. The results should be:

```
preg_match('/[^satb(all)]/', 's')  ==> should be false (and is)
preg_match('/[^satb(all)]/', 'sall')  ==> should be false (and is)
preg_match('/[^satb(all)]/', 'alsl')  ==> should be true but is not (the l's are not part of 'all')
```

I've tried many different combinations but I can't get it right. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You should write more clearly what you want.

Comment: True enough. Sometimes the translation from logic to the written word is harder than writing code! In the end, having an answer the way it is written will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

character class only matches for single characters. 
I think you want is this:

```
if ( preg_match('/^(all|[satb]+)$/', $string) ) {
  // string is valid, do something
} else {
  // string is invalid, do something
}
```

This will match true for the following:

```
$string = "all";
$string = "s";
$string = "a";
$string = "t";
$string = "b";
```

Comment: Almost. While it will match for alls, it won't match for sall

Comment: It won't match for "alls" either.  Your requirement was (s OR a OR t OR b) OR all.

Comment: The above will match for any string ending in 's' 'a' 't' 'b'. So xxxa will incorrectly match

Comment: @mseifert oops you're right, i forgot to group the alternation. see edited code

Comment: 'satb' => false (should be true). Adding a + like so: `'/^(all|[satb])+$/'` fixes that but allows for 'aaa' which I can live with.  My title did say 'simple'! Go ahead and fix the post and I will mark it correct.

Comment: @mseifert oh okay, if that's what works for you, rock on; i edited my post